# summing up a column in a csv file based on user search

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have the following csv file:

data.cvs

```
school,students,teachers,subs
us-school1,10,2,0
us-school2,20,4,2
uk-school1,10,2,0
de-school1,10,3,1
de-school1,15,3,3
```

I am trying to have a user search for the school country (us or uk, or de)
and then sum up the corresponding column. (e.g. sum all students in us-* etc.)
So far i am able to search using the raw_input and display column contents corresponding to the country, appreciate if someone can give me some pointers on how i can achive this.

desired output:

Country: us

Total students: 30

Total teachers: 6

Total subs: 2

--

```
import csv
import re
search = raw_input('Enter school (e.g. us: ')
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
       school = row['school']
       students = row['students']
       teachers = row['teachers']
       sub = row['subs']

       if re.match(search, schools) is not None:
             print students
```

Comment: You could do this with `pandas`. Look up `groupby` and `aggregate`, and think about what you want to happen if the school doesn't match anything in your data.

Comment: thanks.. is there any other approach other than pandas?

Comment: Hi @zig let me know if that solves the issue :), if it does, don't forget mark the answer with the check box top left under the scores

Comment: i was getting the output like this:


country us has 1020 students

and notice it was doing string contcat...

so i added this and it works...


`students = int(row['students'])`

i believe the csv output via the csv module is always in str type irrespective of the data. so had to add 

`int(row['fieldname'])`

Comment: @zig great, I will add it to the answer, sorry I missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be solved with something like this:

```
import csv

search = raw_input('Enter school (e.g. us: ')
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    result_countrys = {}
    for row in reader:
      students = int(row['students'])
      teachers = int(row['teachers'])
      subs = int(row['subs'])
      subs = row['subs']
      country = school[: 2]
      if country in result_countrys:
        count = result_countrys[country]
        count['students'] = count['students'] + students
        count['teachers'] = count['teachers'] + teachers
        count['subs'] = count['subs'] + subs
      else :
        dic = {}
        dic['students'] = students
        dic['teachers'] = teachers
        dic['subs'] = subs
        result_countrys[country] = dic

for k, v in result_countrys[search].iteritems():
    print("country " + str(search) + " has " + str(v) + " " + str(k))
```

I tryed out with this set of values:

```
reader = [{'school': 'us-school1', 'students': 20, 'teachers': 6, 'subs': 2}, {'school': 'us-school2', 'students': 20, 'teachers': 6, 'subs': 2}, {'school': 'uk-school1', 'students': 20, 'teachers': 6, 'subs': 2}]
```

and the result is:

```
Enter school (e.g. us):  us
country us has 30 students
country us has 6 teachers
country us has 2 subs
```

Answer (score 1):

That's relatively easy to do - all you need is a dict to hold group your countries, and then just add together all of the values:

```
import collections
import csv

result = {}  # store the results
with open("data.csv", "rb") as f:  # open our file
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)  # use csv.DictReader for convenience
    for row in reader:
        country = row.pop("school")[:2]  # get our country
        result[country] = result.get(country, collections.defaultdict(int))  # country group
        for column in row:  # loop through all other columns
            result[country][column] += int(row[column])  # add them together

# Now you can use or print your result by country:
for country in result:
    print("Country: {}".format(country))
    print("Total students: {}".format(result[country].get("students", 0)))
    print("Total teachers: {}".format(result[country].get("teachers", 0)))
    print("Total subs: {}\n".format(result[country].get("subs", 0)))
```

This is also universal as you can add additional number columns (e.g. `janitors` :D) and it will happily sum them together, but keep in mind that it works only with integers (if you want floats, replace the references to `int` with float) and it expects that every field except school is a number.

Comment: awesome, very useful and i like the comments too, really helpful for a learner like me... :)

Comment: Really nice zwer, very clear, plus one :) I loved your work